# PyInstaller and Pyogrio write_Dataframe problem in graphical EXE

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I wrote a file that converts excel to shapefiles. In Pycharm it works, well like a charm. ^^
But when I compile it with PyInstaller to exe the write_Dataframe() function, that´s imported from pyogrio, doesn´t write the file.

The GUI ist still fully responsive, but no SHP is written and I don´t get any error messages.

Has this to do with rights or is it an hidden import missing. (Mine are at the moment ['pyogrio._err', 'pyogrio._geometry', 'pyogrio.errors', 'pyogrio._io', 'pyogrio._ogr'])

I´ll add my spec-file for pyinstaller below, my original code is a little to long for it but the line that isn´t executed is this one :

```
write_dataframe(geotable, path, encoding='utf-8')
```

.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['EXCEL2SHP.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['pyogrio._err', 'pyogrio._geometry', 'pyogrio.errors', 'pyogrio._io', 
        'pyogrio._ogr'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='EXCEL2SHP',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon='icon.ico',
)
```

Comment: What value does `path` have? Is it a relative path? What is it relative _to?_ Your files might be getting written, just not to where you think.

Comment: no it´s an absolute windows path. I don´t know if windows is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by just using fiona instead of pyogrio:

```
geotable.to_file(path, mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', encoding='utf-8')
```

This problem is exclusive to Windows!
The important thing that threw me off of fiona in the beginning was that I would prompt a "path is not a directory" error.
This happenend because my filedialog.asksaveasfile() created an empty file and even closing the filedialog "f.close()" or deleting it didnt help here.
I worked around this problem by deleting the created file after creation:

```
os.remove(path_out) # delete empty placeholder file
```

I hope this helps anyone else stumbling over this error.